# joomla, CSS - show joomla module only for smartphone screens

Tags: css, joomla

I have a module in Joomla I setup that I want to only appear when a screen size gets to a mobile smartphone size.

In my module there is a field that allows me to insert some custom CSS like the following image.

[image]

at the bottom of that same page I have a "Module Class Suffix Parameter" field

[image]

**First: I am assuming that in this field I can add another class label such as "box1 thisisit"?**

then in the custom CSS field I added

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) { .thisisit { display:block; } }
```

Ultimately what I want is for that particular module to show only when the screen size is 320 - 480. Otherwise I do not want it to show.

If I am doing this the hard way please show me how to do it easier. Everything I tried as I described has no effect.

Comment: are you using a bootstrap template? Some template frameworks have special classes that can be used to only display something on specific screen sizes

Comment: yes its responsive. You can see the site at www.gvchristianschool.com

Comment: should be able to just add the class `visible-phone` and it will just be visible on mobile phones

Comment: Post this as a solution @DavidFritsch so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to just add the class visible-phone and it will just be visible on mobile phones. Add that in the "Module Class Suffix" box in the settings.

You can use all of the "Responsive Utility Classes" in most Joomla installations: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive